# How to handle indexed categories with PHP & MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a shopping website and I allow users to list products. When they add a new listing, they must enter values from select box into  `main_category,sub_category and leaf_category` fields in `products_tbl`.These fields are indexed because they make queries fast when viewing products. There is also `is_reviewed` flag in `products_tbl` which is 0 by default.

In my admin dashboard I get all listings that are not reviewed and check if they are in the right category. Almost all the time customers make mistake when they list so I edit the listing and update the indexed `main_category,sub_category and leaf_category` fields and change `is_reviewed` flag to 1. This means I have to update every time users list in wrong category and Its really becoming slow.

so what is the best way to do this? I have thought about creating another table and new listings stay there. so after reviewing I add them to to the `products_tbl` with correct categories. But I am not sure if this a good solution. I appreciate your help in advance

Comment: `Almost all the time customers make mistake` maybe you have a UX problem?

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: No what I meant is,  out of 50 new listings I find like 5-10 listings that are in the wrong category everyday. can you recommend me a good solution for this please?

Comment: I'd consider 10-20% mistakes in user actions a probable UX problem. Are the categories easy to navigate and properly separated (or are many similar)? Do you tell them it's important for their listing? Do you help them based on the title/text they've written and suggest similar categories? etc

Comment: I tried to make this the first step and easy as possible. When a user adds a new listing the first they see is a select box of categories. when they select one, children(sub categories) of the selected categories are fetched in second box via ajax and so on..everything else comes after they finish with categories. But I did not add suggestion.

Comment: perhaps the category descriptions are not very clear, or there are too many to choose from, or perhaps your definition of the "right" category is different to the users' understanding - it's potentially subjective. Also, have you considered allowing things to be in multiple categories (e.g. like the topic tags on Stackoverflow questions)? Perhaps some things are not an obvious good fit for a single category and so users are confused. Unless the UX is bad (and just from a description we can't really advise) then it's probably more of a semantics / business process question than a coding one.

Comment: I think you guys are right,I was hoping if there is a magic trick for this but  I will check my website UX instead. Thank you for your time. Have a good day